# Exporting to PDF Macro Missing Shapes

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have a macro that, upon clicking a button, will generate a barcode image (the image is composed of nothing but shapes), and after that, will export 3 sheets to a pdf. The problem I'm having is that doing this will generate the barcode image, but when exporting as a PDF the shapes that were used to generate to barcode don't show up. They will show up if I print or print to pdf without using the export to pdf macro, but that defeats the point of the macro.

An even bigger headache is that this code is on a different version (spreadsheet is a template) of the spreadsheet, but the macro process is working just fine on that spreadsheet. I copy/pasted the working code to the spreadsheet that's giving me trouble and the trouble maker is still not working. Below is the related code. Why are the shapes not being included on the exported PDF?

```
 Sub BevelPrint_Click()
' DisplayBarcode generates a code128 scannable barcode. Max of 14 characters for the selected line width and max width

Call DisplayBarcode

Sheets(Array("(Cal Cert) Page 1 of 3", "(Cal Cert) Page 2 of 3", "(Cal Cert) Page 3 of 3")).Select
   ' If Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show = True Then
   Dim varResult As Variant
   Dim ActBook As Workbook
   Dim defaultPath As String
   Dim WorkbookName As String
   'Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
   ' WorkbookName = fso.GetBaseName(ThisWorkbook.Name)
   WorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("(0) Calibration System QC").Range("B2").Value
   WorkbookName = WorkbookName & " Cert"




   defaultPath = "\\TSISVFP01\MANUFACTURING\W405 - Particle\"
   defaultPath = defaultPath & WorkbookName
        'displays the save file dialog
   varResult = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:= _
            "PDF File (*.pdf), *.pdf, Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Save Cert as PDF", _
            InitialFileName:=defaultPath)

   If varResult <> False Then
      ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        varResult, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
        True
    End If
   ' End If
    Sheets("(0) Calibration System QC").Select
End Sub
```

```
Sub DisplayBarcode()
Dim s As Shape
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("(Cal Cert) Page 1 of 3").Activate
   For Each s In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("(Cal Cert) Page 1 of 3").Shapes
        If s.Name Like "*Straight*" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("(Cal Cert) Page 1 of 3").Shapes(s.Name).Select
         Selection.Delete
        End If

   Next s

   Code128Generate_v2 184, 72, 9, 1.5, Worksheets("(Cal Cert) Page 1 of 3"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("(0) Calibration System QC").Range("B2"), 40
    Dim t As Shape
    For Each t In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("(Cal Cert) Page 1 of 3").Shapes
        t.ControlFormat.PrintObject = True
    Next t
End Sub
```

Comment: If you export the "problem" sheet to PDF manually does it work?

Comment: Yes - going through and print -> print to pdf will have the shapes visible.

Comment: Print to pdf, or save as PDF ?  `ExportAsFixedFormat ` is the same as save as PDF.

Comment: Initially I was testing this with print to pdf, but going and saving as PDF (I didn't realize there was a difference) I'm getting the same issue as when I use the macro.